# Prove that two segments are congruent in the arbelos

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, circles

### Background Info + Problem

I teach HS Geometry to middle school age students. I generally like to try to solve problems instead of looking up the answer, but this week a student emailed me a problem that I don't think I'll be able to solve on my own. So I thought I'd ask it here since I haven't been able to find a solution online. **The problem is to prove that $\overline{AC} \cong \overline{EF}$.** The diagram is known as the arbelos. Information can be found at [wolfram|alpha](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Arbelos.html), [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbelos). The green circle in the construction is often referred to as one of the two "twin-circles" or "Archimedes circles."

[image: Basic problem diagram: prove AC]

### Here's a hint

I have researched this, and found the problem presented in a few places. I think that a distorted version of this problem was the inspiration for a study of the arbelos by H.P. Boas. Who, in the end of [his work (pdf)](http://www.math.tamu.edu/%7Eharold.boas/preprints/arbelos.pdf) poses the problem as an exercise to the reader. He offers the hint that

> It suffices to show that $\overline{AF} \perp \overline{EF}$, for then $\triangle AFG \sim \triangle ECG$. Invert in a circle centered at A that cuts the right-hand twin circle orthogonally, and prove that the point F is left fixed.

One sub-question to the main point, is a more general geometric question: Is there a good way to break this proof down into simpler parts? I could keep track of the various ratios throughout the 20+ steps of this construction, but that would be difficult to write and probably more difficult for someone else to follow.

### Construction

If it is helpful, I will present the steps of the construction.

1. Given $\overline{AB}$ with midpoint $C$
2. Construct $\odot C$ with radius $\overline{CA}$
3. Let point $D$ lie on $\overline{AB}$
4. Points $E$ and $F$ are the midpoints of segments $AD$ and $DB$
5. Construct circles $E$ with radius $\overline{EA}$ and $F$ with radius $\overline{FA}$. This is the basic arbelos.

To construct the tangent or "twin-circles"

1. Construct perpendicular lines to segment $AB$ through $E$ and $F$. Let point $G$ be the intersection point of the perpendicular and circle $E$ and point $H$ be the intersection point of the perpendicular and circle $F$.
2. Let $I$ be the intersection of $FG$ and $EH$

[image: Arbelos construction - ref 1]

3. Construct circle $D$ with radius $\overline{DI}$
4. Let J and K be the points where circle $D$ intersects segment $AB$
5. Construct perpendiculars to segment $AB$ through $J$ and $K$
6. At the intersection of the perpendicular from K and the circle with center F and radius $\overline{FJ}$, construct circle $L$ with radius equal to $DK$
7. At the intersection of $\overrightarrow{FL}$ and the circle of center $F$ and radius $\overline{FD}$ find point $M$, at the intersection of $\overrightarrow{FL}$ and the perpendicular from D, find point $N$

[image: Update (#2) final construction]

In the construction I outlined above, I want to prove that $\overline{AD} \cong \overline{MN}$.

## How would you prove $\overline{AD} \cong \overline{MN}$?

Comment: The ["special case" of Descartes' Theorem for Kissing Circles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes'_theorem#Special_cases) lets you compute the radius of the green circle. From here, the problem reduces to algebra. Boas seems to have something else in mind, however; probably something easier. I'm still investigating. :)

Comment: @Blue The radius of the green circle is equal to the radius of circle D with radius $\overline{DK}$. At least to me the Algebra seems like it must get very difficult, but I might have to dig in and see how far I can get.

Comment: I'm not seeing Boas' intended soln, but here's an approach: Let $X$ be the pt of tangency of the twin circle w/ $CE$, and $Y$ the pt of tangency w/the big semicircle. Introduce $AY$ & $BY$, which form a right angle at $Y$. Convince yourself that $X$ is on $AY$, and that $E$ is on $BY$-extended. Then $\triangle ACX \sim \triangle ECB$. Let $Z$ be the midpt of $CX$, and $G$ the midpt of $BC$. Then $AZ$ and $EG$ are medians of similar triangles, creating similar sub-triangles: $\triangle ACZ \sim \triangle ECG$. Thus, $A$, $Z$, $F$ are collinear (why?); but $ZF \perp EF$ (why?), so $AF\perp EF$.

Comment: @Blue I'm not sure that **X** or **Y** should exist. CE is not tangent to a twin circle unless I'm missing something?

Comment: I'm referring to the original diagram (not your construction), where tangency to $CE$ is part of what makes a twin circle a twin circle ... isn't it?

Comment: @Blue Look at the twin circle constructed in the second diagram $\overleftrightarrow{HF}$ intersects it twice. This is the same for $\overleftrightarrow{CE}$ and the left twin circle. In the construction, CF and HE intersect and give the radius of circle D and radius $\overline{DI}$. Note that the twin circles share this radius.

Comment: The counterpart of the first diagram's $CE$ is the third diagram's $DN$, not $HF$. Anyway ... I'll restate my comment in an answer, where I can provide my own diagram.

Comment: @Blue I think I left the points consistent, give me a minute and I'll edit the question to maintain all the points in the diagram. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: When I speak of "the first diagram", I'm mean the one in the "Background Info + Problem" section of your question, not your construction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19063/discussion-between-nick-h-and-blue).

Comment: @Blue I appreciate your suggested proof much more. All of the statements you make are correct. I was hoping to be able to construct a true proof where I make the minimal assumptions necessary to accomplish the proof. It seems possible to prove without adding in leaps of faith. I think you are making statements like "convince yourself that..." because it would be exhausting to supply the reasoning for a statement like X is on AY. I suppose that is part of the motivation for my question -- how would I reason that, as you assert, X is on AY? I know it is true, but I'm not sure I can prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restating my comment as an answer with diagrams (and slightly-different labeling) ...

---

[image]

Let $X$ be the point of tangency of the twin circle $\bigcirc R$ with $\overline{CE}$, and $Y$ the point of tangency of $\bigcirc R$ with the big semicircle, $\stackrel{\frown}{AB}$.

Introduce $\overline{AY}$ and $\overline{BY}$, which form a right angle at $Y$. Convince yourself that $X$ is on $\overline{AY}$, and that $E$ is on $\overline{BY}$-extended. (This isn't *difficult*, but it's a bit tedious. See the "footnote" below.) Then $\triangle ACX \sim \triangle ECB$.

[image]

Now, let $Z$ be the midpoint of $\overline{CX}$, which is in fact the center of $\bigcirc CFX$. (Why?) Then $\overline{AZ}$ and $\overline{EQ}$ are corresponding medians of similar triangles, creating similar sub-triangles: $\triangle ACZ \sim \triangle ECQ$. Consequently, $\angle AXC$ is congruent to $\angle EQC$, which is itself congruent to $\angle FZX$ (why?); this implies that $A$, $Z$, $F$ are collinear. But $Z$ is such that $\overline{ZF}\perp\overline{EF}$ (why?), and we conclude that $\overline{AF}\perp\overline{EF}$.

This is the result from Boas' hint (arrived-at via different means); from here, showing $\overline{AC}\cong\overline{EF}$ is straightforward: $\triangle ACZ$ and $\triangle EFZ$ are similar right triangles with $\overline{CZ} \cong \overline{FZ}$; therefore, the triangles are actually congruent, and $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{EF}$ are corresponding parts.

**Note.** For some reason, I'm just not seeing Boas' suggestion to use an inversion to establish $\overline{AF}\perp\overline{EF}$. I don't doubt that his approach is more elegant, especially since the problem is taken from an article celebrating the convenience of inversion. Even without an inversion, I think my argument could use considerable refinement. (It seems like we should be able to take better advantage of $\bigcirc CFX$, which also passes through the intersection of $\bigcirc P$ and $\overline{AY}$.)

**Note 2.** It's worth mentioning that the radius of the twin circle is given by $\frac{pq}{p+q}$, which is half the [harmonic mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean) of $p$ and $q$, where $p$ and $q$ are the radii of $\bigcirc P$ and $\bigcirc Q$. (Indeed, the construction @Nick used incorporates the ["crossed ladders" derivation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean#In_geometry) of the mean.) The fact that this value is symmetric in $p$ and $q$ explains the "twin" part of the name "twin circle": the counterpart of $\bigcirc R$ that is tangent to $\bigcirc P$ has the same size.

---

**Footnote.** To show that $X$ is on $\overline{AY}$ and $E$ is on $\overline{BY}$-extended, consider the following, where I've introduced $O$ as the center of the large semicircle:

[image]

Certainly, $\overline{OY}$ passes through $R$, because $\bigcirc O$ and $\bigcirc R$ are tangent at $Y$. And, since $\overline{RX}\parallel\overline{OA}$, we have that $\triangle OAY$ and $\triangle RXY$ are isosceles triangles with congruent vertex angles; they're similar, so that $\angle OYA\cong\angle OYX$. This (along with the fact that $A$ and $X$ are on the same side of $\overline{OY}$) implies that $A$, $X$, $Y$ are collinear.

Likewise, $B$, $W$, $Y$ are collinear, where $W$ is the diametric opposite of $X$ in $\bigcirc R$. Observe that $E$ lies on a line through $C$ and $X$, and on line through $R$ and $Q$ (not shown above, but shown earlier). $E$ is therefore the center of a dilation between $\bigcirc R$ to $\bigcirc Q$. Necessarily, $E$ is on the line through $W$ and $B$. And, since $\angle QBW \cong \angle RWY$, it follows that $Y$ is collinear with $W$ and $B$ (and $E$).

Of course, going through these details greatly amplifies the imperfection of this approach. I trust that there's a way to streamline my argument to avoid all these collinearity arguments, but I haven't found it.

Comment: Happy to mark this as the answer as it is thoughtful and satisfies much of what I was hoping to find here. Your claim that *$\overline{OY}$ passes through R, because $\odot O$ and $\odot R$ are tangent at Y.* Is something I would have missed in trying to prove colinearity.

Comment: It turns out that [Cut-the-Knot has a discussion of the twin circles, and a spare!](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/CircleTriplet.shtml) The inversive proof there may relate to the argument hinted-at by Boas for this problem.